# What is the difference between mysqli_affected_rows and mysqli_num_rows?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The [PHP docs for mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) says

> Returns the number of rows in the result set.

The [PHP docs for mysqli_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) says

> Returns the number of rows affected by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query.

_num_rows is called on a result, and _affected_rows is called on a connection. Since I think they do the same thing(correct this assumption if I'm wrong), I'm wondering whether one works better than the other, and which situations would call for which function.

Aren't *number of rows affected* and *number of rows in the result set* synonymous?

Comment: In the case of simply checking if a query was successful (... if($con->___rows > 0){}), I find mysqli_num_rows to be more straightforward. Since _num_rows works on inserts, how is this different than affected rows? Wouldn't any result set contain "affected" rows?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`num_rows` tells you *how many rows there are in the result set you just selected with a `SELECT` query.* `affected_rows` tells you *how many rows where affected by an `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `REPLACE` or `DELETE` query.* The difference is obvious:

```
$resultSet = mysqli_query($c, 'SELECT ...');
echo mysqli_num_rows($resultSet);
```

`SELECT` result set goes into `num_rows`.

```
mysqli_query($c, 'UPDATE ...');
echo mysqli_affected_rows($c);
```

No result set, no `num_rows`.

Comment: sorry for deleting my comment I edited it into the question, which made you delete your comment. The key point you said was mysqli_query returns an object of type mysqli_result for SELECT queries only... So they are not useable interchangeably!

Comment: Well, according to [the official doc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php), `affected_rows` and `num_rows` returns the same value for `SELECT` operation

Answer (score 4):

`mysql_affect_rows` counts on how many rows your `UPDATE/INSERT` query was used
and `mysql_num_rows` counts how many rows your `SELECT` statement found

Comment: I feel like you answer was better without the "etc." since "etc." could include SELECT

Comment: But I can use `mysql_num_rows` to count the rows an insert affected, too

Comment: @J-Dizzle Can you really? Since `mysqli_num_rows` requires a `mysqli_result` argument which you only get for `SELECT` queries, I don't see how.

Comment: I suppose I can't ... but how do I verify that inserts are successful?

Comment: You can try to retrive the ´last inserted ID´: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: @J-Dizzle If `mysqli_query('INSERT ...')` returns `true`, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add, in recent versions of mysql this may have changed.

I was recently looking for the difference and found that while yes `mysqli_num_rows` counts how many rows your `SELECT` statement found.

`mysqli_affected_rows` will count how many rows your `UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE/REPLACE` **and** `SELECT` statement 'affected'.

Unless you are trying to compare between the number of rows returned in a `SELECT` statement vs. the number of rows affected in an `UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE/REPLACE` than there is no huge concern over which you need to be using.  If you want to be semantically correct than use the appropriate one for the corresponding statement.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-affected-rows.html

> For SELECT statements, `mysql_affected_rows()`
>   works like `mysql_num_rows()`

Comment: Yes, but you can't use `mysql_num_rows` to get the number of affected rows.

Comment: I realise that. That fact can be inferred from the other answers. I was simply adding to the fact that `affected_rows` is synonymous with all `UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE/REPLACE` **and** `SELECT` statements, not **just** the first four as previous answers are stating.  It was not abundantly clear that one can use `affected_rows` on `SELECT` statements.