# Cannot get data from MySQL table with PHP request

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and MySQL and trying to get a row returned from my table matching input from a HTML form.  Code as follows:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'testdb') 
OR die('Could not connect to the server' . mysqli_connect_error());

$query = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$hits = mysqli_affected_rows($connect);

if ($hits < 1) {
   echo "Incorrect password or username";   
   die("<br /><a href='index.php'>Try Again<a/>");
} else {
   // other not relevant code here
}
```

The var `$hits` always comes back as 0, when there is data in the table matching the query.

`var_dump($result)` returns:

```
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=>
int(4) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }
```

Comment: missing `'` at `mysqli_connect('localhost,` and for `select` query use `mysqli_num_rows`

Comment: Did you check the database connectivity? Also, check the value of $username by printing it..

Comment: Syntax error in first line. mysqli_connect('localhost',....

Comment: Where does `$username` come from?

Comment: @NaveedRamzan You can assume that this is a typo in this question only, if it were in the actual code the `$result` wouldn't contain anything useful.

Comment: yeah sorry the missing ' was a typo. $username came from higher up in the code - it was the username variable... I declared it earlier and thought that it would still be available.  declaring it again solved this, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plz post user name ... 
and try this code .

```
 $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'testdb') 
    OR die('Could not connect to the server' . mysqli_connect_error());

    $username=$_POST['username'];

    $query = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    $hits = mysqli_num_rows($connect);

    if ($hits < 1) {
       echo "Incorrect password or username";   
       die("<br /><a href='index.php'>Try Again<a/>");
    } else {
       // other not relevant code here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to count your result, not the affected rows:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'testdb') 
OR die('Could not connect to the server' . mysqli_connect_error());

$query = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($username) . "'");
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$hits = mysqli_num_rows($connect);

if ($hits < 1) {
   echo "Incorrect password or username";   
   die("<br /><a href='index.php'>Try Again<a/>");
} else {
   // other not relevant code here
}
```

Further: Don't pass the username without sanatizing.

Using the die() function breaks your application. It's better to catch the error and pass this to de view.

Comment: Quote [from the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php): `For SELECT statements mysqli_affected_rows() works like mysqli_num_rows().` So that change doesn't do anything.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25555758/what-is-the-difference-between-mysqli-affected-rows-and-mysqli-num-rows

Answer (score 0):

Use like this :

```
$connect = mysqli_connect(***'localhost'***, 'root', '', 'testdb') 
OR die('Could not connect to the server' . mysqli_connect_error());

$query = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($username) . "'");
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
***$hits = mysqli_num_rows($result);***

if ($hits < 1) {
   echo "Incorrect password or username";   
   die("<br /><a href='index.php'>Try Again<a/>");
} else {
   // other not relevant code here
}
```