# query is getting affected in database but still it is showing error message in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

This section of code is I am using to update password with token verification, I am getting useremail from url in encrypted format, that is why I have used md5 in query.
The query is getting executed and affecting the table correctly, but it keep showing the else error message.

```
    $password= md5($_POST['password']);
    $sqlupdateaccount="UPDATE `mydatabasename`.`usertbl` 
                        SET `password`='$password' 
                        WHERE MD5(`useremail`)='$useremail' 
                        AND `token`='$token'";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sqlupdateaccount);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)  // also used if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)) but still same problem
    {
        header("Location:userlogin.php?s=1");
    } else {
        echo "<h3 class='alert alert-danger'>Something Went Wrong</h3>".mysqli_error($con);
    }
```

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using `MD5()` or `SHA1()`. 
PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: ok should i just replace md5() with password_hash()

Comment: See a detailed explanation about hashing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords).

Comment: I would of course suggest you read up on and use the `password_hash()` functions

Comment: yes i am sendign hashed email in url for password verification,

Comment: Anyways, back on topic: `num_rows` is what you get when you *select* a result set. You're not fetching anything from an `UPDATE`, so this won't have the data you need. What you want instead is the number of affected rows.

Comment: There is a difference between [mysqli_affected_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) and [mysqli_num_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php). Since your query **is not** an select query, you should use mysqli_affected_rows.

Comment: Why you all focused on hashing, this is not the question here at all.

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal i have tried using mysqli_affected_rows($con) but same problem. still i will try one more time

Comment: Thanks @DefinitelynotRafal if have used this condition and it worked  if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0)

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal can you answer the question with new if condition so i can accept it as answer

Comment: Thank you for hashing information, i will update my code with password_hash(), but no one told me what is wrong with MD5() and SHA1(), and down voted my question.

Comment: _“but no one told me what is wrong with MD5() and SHA1()”_ - well who did you _expect_ to tell you, and when & where? Did you expect someone to come by your place in the evening, and read it to you as a bedtime story …? Doing a bit of _reading up_ on what the currently recommended best practices are for stuff like this, is your own responsibility .

Comment: @CBroe thanks for reading all comments and commenting and guiding me to study and research over hashing concept which I was doing, and sorry if I have offended you.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25555758/what-is-the-difference-between-mysqli-affected-rows-and-mysqli-num-rows answer your question?

Comment: @NicoHaase yes that explains the solution to my problem, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mysqli_num_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) should be used when you have a select query.

[mysqli_affected_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) is what you are searching for.

Change `if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {...` to `if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0) {...`